# C# convert float to string or double

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Actual source value is `603459382`.
My C# code return `float` `6.034594E+08`.

When convert to Int32 I got `603459392`, wrong 9 instead of 8.
When convert to string `603459400` seems to rounded.

How do I get right conversion?

Comment: Why wouldn't your code parse an int to begin with?

Comment: Float is a float, with limited precision.  You cannot expect it to store arbitrary number with 100% precision, it's data type limitation.  Try `double`, if you absolutely must

Comment: How are you converting to `Int32`? I doubt that `Int32.Parse("603459382")` would return `603459392`.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a look at `float` (`Single`) [binary representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) we will find that maximum integer part which is not be rounded is `16777216` (which corresponds maximum *mantissa* value + `1`: `1 << 24`) Since

```
 603459382 > 16777216
```

`Single` can't represent the `603459382` value *exactly*, and you should switch to `double` (which has `1 << 53 == 9007199254740992` limit for exact integer value representation)